# Learning management system for/in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

So the idea is simple. I need a learning management system for drupal. Whateve it's a extension or module.

I tried to google it and reached opigno. But it will totally take way to much time to fix it's styles out for 21 century. And also, it's pretty useless. Makes to much problems.

I'd be grateful to any one who will give me any idea!

Thanks,
Kind Regards.

Comment: What kind of functionnalities do you need in your "learning management system" ?

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a school management system module but no result,
If you are not bound to use drupal you may find many plugins in wordpress for the title you mentioned.
you can view the following as an example:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/learnpress/
or this one:
https://themeforest.net/item/lms-learning-management-system-education-lms-wordpress-theme/7867581
and if you forced to find something for drupal I didn't find with my previous search.